# Easiest way to convert from json to correct data type in C#?

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization, deserialization

I have used https://json2csharp.com/
But what often happens is the app breaking since the deserialized response isn't always in the correct data type.
Is there a way to easily fix this issue?
Maybe set all API response parameter data types to string (and then manually parse to the required type once I actually use it), except maybe bool?

Anyone got a solution other than manually changing the data types?

I am attempting some API testing, but some of the APIs I use return hundreds of parameters, so changing everything by hand simply takes too long.

Comment: The easy converters make very generalized assumptions by taking the most likely immediate answer.  Consider `{"value":0}`.  Deserialized would make `value` an `int`.  But maybe I want it to be `long`.  A json converter does not know this.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar haha. Still, thanks for the explanation, do you have any advice on how to approach this other than manually changing parameters as required? :D

Comment: try to use `dynamic` to extract the values that you want from the JSON and check if they are not null then you can continue the process.
Here is an example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326146/13124794)